# Find All the tables related to a stored procedure in Azure Synapse Datawarehouse

Tags: azure, t-sql, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Is there a simple way to find out all the tables referenced in a stored procedure in azure analytics data warehouse other than parsing the stored procedure code? I tried few commands like **sp_tables**, **sp_depends** but none seems to be working in azure data warehouse.

Comment: sp_depends does not support in Synapse dedicated sql pools.

Answer (score 4):

[sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is supported in Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools, but only supports tables, views and functions at this time.  A simple example:

`SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies;`

So you are left either parsing `sys.sql_modules`.  Something like this is imperfect (ie doesn't deal with schema name, square brackets, partial matches etc) but could server as a starting point:

```
SELECT 
    sm.[definition],
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) schemaName,
    OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) tableName
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
    CROSS JOIN sys.tables t
WHERE sm.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_test')
  AND sm.[definition] Like '%' + t.name + '%';
```

I actually use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) with dedicated SQL pools so your dependencies can't get out of step and are trackable via the project.

Comment: It's such a shame they released Purview without this capability.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),definition 
FROM sys.all_sql_modules 
WHERE definition LIKE '%your_table_name%'
```